# Understanding Apfloat and its precision

Tags: java, apfloat

I'm using an application which uses mm and inches to draw scaled drawings. I need to convert from one to another without losing precision. I'm struggling with accuracy and have turned to the Apfloat package. Can someone explain... if I start with 100mm, convert it to inches and then back again to Mm why I get a loss of precision??

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Apint mm = new Apint(100);
    System.out.println("mm = " + mm);

    // 25.4mm in 1 inch
    Apfloat toInches = new Apfloat("25.4");

    // 100mm / 25.4 = x-Inches      
    Apfloat inches = mm.divide(toInches);
    System.out.println("mm - > Inch = " + inches);

    // x-Inches x 25.4 = 100mm
    Apfloat backToMm = inches.multiply(toInches);
    System.out.println("Inch - > mm = " + backToMm);
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
mm = 100
mm - > Inch = 3.93
Inch - > mm = 9.99e1
```

No matter how big I set the precision property I still get the reoccurring 9.999...

Comment: Sounds like a floating point rounding error to me.

Comment: @Powerlord I'd agree, but I was lead to believe this particular package was meant to be accurate and was preferred over BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I wasn't familiar with Apfloat, so I started reading its documentation.

Apparently, if you use the `public Apfloat(String value)` constructor, the precision of the number is the number of digits in the string.

In this case, you've specified "25.4", which is 3 digits.

However, to get around this issue, you can use the `public Apfloat(String value, long precision)` constructor which allows you to specify the precision so that you can handle numbers with more decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding mode is undefined. To get a rounded result, use `ApfloatMath.round()`